# React Native navigation (4.x) props become null between screens

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a stack of screens that are used to create objects that will be displayed at the end.

While passing parameters through screens there is no problem until the last one.

When you confirm on the last screen the function that navigates to the dashboard (where all objects are listed) triggers, it goes where it needs to go, but at the moment of retrieving the parameters in the constructor they are returned as `null`, even if by debugger I can clearly see that the prop is successfully passed to the navigate function.

The piece of code below calls an `api` from the backend to retrieve the current `user`, if successful the `openDashboardHouses` function is triggered:

```
new UsersApi(context).apiUsersCurrentMeGet().then(resp => {
            console.log(resp);
                     // passing context - user - house object 
            openDashboardHouses(context, resp, context.state.house);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
            AlertHelper.showSimpleErrorAlert();
        });
```

The `openDashboardHouses` function is just the single line of code to navigate:

```
export function openDashboardHouses(context: Component<NavigationProps, any>, user: User, house: House = null) {
    context.props.navigation.navigate(dashboardHousesRoute, {user: user, house: house}); // During debugging the values on this line are correctly filled
}
```

Then on the next screen it should get the props in the constructor and save them in the state:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        setHeaderTitleLocalized(props, 'screens.dashboard.title');

        this.state = {
            loading: false,
            user: getUserFromNavigationProps(this), 
            houses: [],
            resources: [],
            created_house: getHouseFromNavigationProps(this), 
        };
    }
```

As you can see I have two helper functions, neither of them returns anything

```
export function getUserFromNavigationProps(context: Component<NavigationProps, any>) {
    return context.props.navigation.getParam(USER_KEY); // USER_KEY = 'user'
}

export function getHouseFromNavigationProps(context: Component<NavigationProps, any>): House {
    return context.props.navigation.getParam(HOUSE_KEY); // HOUSE_KEY = 'house'
}
```

Any idea of what is going on?

**Additional info:** that house prop is created in the first screen and it's passed in the same way in all of them. It's just the last one that doesn't want to cooperate

Dependencies:

React Native:

```
├─ react-native@0.62.2
│  ├─ @sentry/react-native@^1.0.0
```

React Navigation:

```
├─ @react-navigation/core@3.5.0
├─ @react-navigation/native@3.6.2
├─ @react-navigation/web@1.0.0-alpha.9
├─ react-navigation-drawer@1.4.0
├─ react-navigation-stack@1.5.3
├─ react-navigation-tabs@1.2.0
├─ react-navigation@3.12.1
│  ├─ @react-navigation/core@~3.5.0
│  ├─ @react-navigation/native@~3.6.1
│  ├─ react-navigation-drawer@~1.4.0
│  ├─ react-navigation-stack@~1.5.0
│  └─ react-navigation-tabs@~1.2.0
```

Comment: Which version of react-navigation are you running?

Comment: @aetheode
 @react-navigation/core@3.5.0 --
├─ @react-navigation/native@3.6.2 --
├─ @react-navigation/web@1.0.0-alpha.9 --
├─ react-navigation-drawer@1.4.0 --
├─ react-navigation-stack@1.5.3 --
├─ react-navigation-tabs@1.2.0 --
├─ react-navigation@3.12.1 --
│  ├─ @react-navigation/core@~3.5.0 --
│  ├─ @react-navigation/native@~3.6.1 --
│  ├─ react-navigation-drawer@~1.4.0 --
│  ├─ react-navigation-stack@~1.5.0 --
│  └─ react-navigation-tabs@~1.2.0 --

Comment: Ah so seems like the overall version is react-native 4.x

Comment: @aetheode is it a compatibility issue? Because everything works fine everywhere but here

Comment: Nah I just needed the version so I could look through the docs correctly. Trying to come up with what the problem might be

Comment: @aetheode oh, ok, thank you. I edited the versions in the question if that helps

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the screen you are navigating to could be outside of the context of the screen you are navigating from, so it sorta gets lost. Sorry, it's been awhile since I've worked with this early of a version of react-navigation. Might you could explore upgrading your library to the last version as the have introduce different context providers that make data management like this much easier, imo

Comment: @aetheode no problem, I'll look into contexts and see if i can figure something out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found a "solution", apparently the constructor (only this one for some reason) is broken or something and can't assign values.

According to [4.x docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/params) you can get all navigation props with

```
this.props.navigation.state.params
```

So instead of trying to set it as a state i just use this as an object where i need it.

For example

```
console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params.house);
```

prints the right thing.

N.B. *I was not able because my project is already too big, but when you have the chance always update your dependencies to the last version to avoid this sort of bugs*

Comment: Congrats on finding the solution

Comment: @aetheode just because you helped me find the right docs to eviscerate hahaha